# how to check if player has been destroyed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in the game I am creating when the player dies I destroy that object and move to a different scene which simply says you died, however the camera follows the player, this creates an error when the player is destroyed as it can no longer follow the player I cannot think of how to scan to see if the player has been destroyed (from inside the cameras script)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMotor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform lookAt;
    public float boundX = 0.001f;
    public float boundY = 0.001f;

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 delta = Vector3.zero;

        //to check if inside the bounds on X axis
        float deltaX = lookAt.position.x - transform.position.x;
        if (deltaX > boundX || deltaX < -boundX)
        {
            if (transform.position.x < lookAt.position.x)
            {
                delta.x = deltaX - boundX;
            }
            else
            {
                delta.x = deltaX + boundX;
            }
        }

        //to check if inside the bounds on Y axis
        float deltaY = lookAt.position.y - transform.position.y;
        if (deltaY > boundY || deltaY < -boundY)
        {
            if (transform.position.y < lookAt.position.y)
            {
                delta.y = deltaY - boundY;
            }
            else
            {
                delta.y = deltaY + boundY;
            }
        }

        transform.position += new Vector3(delta.x, delta.y, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hide the player and mark it dead in your script and if dead. Then move to new scene

Comment: I don't do Unity but it seems like you would create an event on player death and then have that take care of all the things that need to happen when the player dies, like the camera, etc. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events)

Answer (score 0):

When the object is destroyed, it's components are destroyed too. So You can simply check if Transform object is null.

```
if (lookAt == null)
{
   Debug.Log("Object has destroyed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if **lookAt** is not null before looking at the player...

```
private void LateUpdate()
{
    if(lookAt != null){
        Vector3 delta = Vector3.zero;

        //to check if inside the bounds on X axis
        float deltaX = lookAt.position.x - transform.position.x;
        if (deltaX > boundX || deltaX < -boundX)
        {
            if (transform.position.x < lookAt.position.x)
            {
                delta.x = deltaX - boundX;
            }
            else
            {
                delta.x = deltaX + boundX;
            }
        }

        //to check if inside the bounds on Y axis
        float deltaY = lookAt.position.y - transform.position.y;
        if (deltaY > boundY || deltaY < -boundY)
        {
            if (transform.position.y < lookAt.position.y)
            {
                delta.y = deltaY - boundY;
            }
            else
            {
                delta.y = deltaY + boundY;
            }
        }

        transform.position += new Vector3(delta.x, delta.y, 0);
    }
}
```